# I am stuck in while True loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

Python 2.7. I am new to Python and I am stuck with while True loop. Simple program to calculate salary. When 'standard' entered as a letter, it catches the error and jumps again to the line 'Enter your rate'. I want it to be repeated only where the error was captured and not starting to input all info all over again. Can someone help please?

```
while True:
 try:
    rate = float(raw_input("Enter your rate: "))
    error = float(rate)
    standard = float(raw_input("Enter total standard hours 100%: "))
    error = float(standart) 
 except:
    print 'Not a number'
    continue       
 else:
    sum = standard * rate 
    print sum
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: add `break` in the end of else, after `print sum`

Answer (score 2):

```
while True:
    try:
        rate = float(raw_input("Enter your rate: "))
        standard = float(raw_input("Enter total standard hours 100%: "))
    except ValueError:
        print 'Not a number'      
    else:
        sum = standard * rate 
        print sum
        break
```

You need to add a break at the end. Also you dont need to write `error = float(..)` when you are already trying to typecaste it in the input step.

Also, there is a typo in the line `error = float(standart)` . This will cause it to give exceptions forever.

Another good practice is to specify the type of error you expect ( ValueError ). This would help prevent things like typos.

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting standard and rate out of the same loop, like so.

```
def get_input(text):
    while 1:
        try:
            value = float(raw_input(text))
            break
        except:
            print 'Not a Number'
    return value

rate = get_input("Enter your rate: ")
standard = get_input("Enter total standard hours 100%: ")

sum = standard * rate
print(sum)
```

This way only the value that failed will be re-queried.

Comment: It does make sense and it did work. Thank you. 
Can you please only explain why did you put '1' after 'while'?

Comment: I'm glad it worked.  In python 1 will evaluate as True, and 0 as false. So while 1 is equivalent to while True.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `continue` instruction is not needed, as `else`
instruction is executed only if no exception has been thrown.

But to exit the loop in the "positive" case, add `break` instruction
after `print sum`.

And one more remark: Change `standart` to `standard`.

Answer (score -1):

```
while True:
try:
    rate = float(raw_input("Enter your rate: "))
    standard = float(raw_input("Enter total standard hours 100%: "))
except ValueError:
    print( 'Not a number' )
else:
    sum = standard * rate 
    print(sum)
    break
```